# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am having this issue even if i have already upgraded my python and its 64bit.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

My python is up to date (3.12.1).

I Have Tried Updating Python but still getting this issue about Tensorflow Installation. How to resolve this? I have even installed `C++ vc_redist.x64.exe`

Comment: Tensorflow is not yet available for python 3.12, you  have to downgrade to 3.11